# how to plugin VS class library dll to apache cordova. any good example?

Tags: cordova, dll, reference

I want to start my first Mobile App development using Visual studio 2015 tools for Apache cordova. I understand it is a html , css and js platform for building mobile app.

in order to use a class library dll(mastermechanism) which contains some business logic, linqtosql class and so on. I have to refer to this dll from the Apache cordova Custom plugin.

I have search for days on a very good example on how to set up the custom plugin and also the plugin xml file but without success.

The project am I m undertaking should should target multi platforms (android,ios, windows phone and windows)

My Aim is to be able to call methods in the master mechanism (dll).

is there anyone out there that can brief me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin development guide walks you through all the steps necessary for the core plugin and then there are links at the bottom for the specific steps you have to take for each platform:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

However, you will need to port your library to each platform in some manner.  You cannot take your DLL and run it unmodified on iOS or Android.  Either you convert it to the native language for each platform or you will have to find another wrapper library / tool that would then be wrapped in the plugin in...  That may be quite a bit of work...

My suggestion, would be putting the logic of the DLL on a server and have it accessed via a restful api.  That way you don't have to to write a custom plugin and the app would essentially be the same on all platforms.

The other approach is to look at Xamarin instead of Cordova.  Xamarin has much better support for wrapping native code and pushing to multiple platforms.

Comment: Thank you so much Brad.
I believe you suggested that should use just jquery service to fetch data or access method in a hosted server . and in this case i don't need to do much work in trying tom make dll works for all platforms.

I have that in mind but my fear was that calling methods and fetching data frequently might hinder performance. but i think there is a way i can handle that. thank you